# How can I delete a dynamical control from an UpdatePanel at the click of a button?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET `UpdatePanel` where I add other panels dynamically. Each of these smaller panels has their own "Delete" Button. 
When I click on one of those "Delete" button, I want the corresponding panel to be deleted. Instead, what happens is: I press "Delete", nothing happens, then when I do another operation that causes a `PostBack`, the panel is deleted. (Too late)

I draw every dynamical control on `PostBack` and when I click the Delete button, its handler (which deletes the panel I want) only occurs after I draw every control, so I don't see any changes immediately.

Here's the code that is called on every postback:

```
private void drawForm()
    {
 if (Session["controls"] != null)
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
            Ccontrols = (Dictionary<Label, Control>)Session["controls"];
            int index = 1;
            foreach (var entry in Ccontrols)
            {
                Panel cPanel = new Panel();
                cPanel.CssClass = "controldiv";
                cPanel.ID = "cpanel" + index;
                Button closebtn = new Button();
                closebtn.Text = "Delete";
                closebtn.ID = "closebtn" + index++;
                closebtn.Click += new EventHandler(closeControl);
                cPanel.Controls.Add(entry.Key);
                cPanel.Controls.Add(entry.Value);
                cPanel.Controls.Add(closebtn);
                cPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                cPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                closebtn.CssClass = "closebutton";
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(cPanel);

            }

            FormPanel.Update();
        }
        else
        {
            FormPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Clear();
        }
```

Here is the DeleteButton handler:

```
 private void closeControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String id = (sender as Button).ID;
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Remove(PlaceHolder1.FindControl("cpanel" + id));
        foreach (Control c in (sender as Button).Parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Label)
            {
                Ccontrols.Remove((Label)c);
            }
        }
        Session["controls"] = Ccontrols;
        drawForm();

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your triggers in UpdatePanel.
I would be able to help you better if you would post your html code where you have created your UpdatePanel.